# How to remove rows with NAs only if they are present in more than certain percentage of columns?

Tags: r, na

I want to use na.omit (data) for the following example dataset, but on a condition so as to remove rows with NAs only when they are present in lets say "more than 30%" of the columns.

data:

```
        C1     C2     C3     C4     C5
Gene1   0.07   NA     0.05   0.07   0.07
Gene2   0.2    0.18   0.16   0.15   0.15
Gene3   NA     0.93   0.9    NA     0.92
Gene4   0.32   0.05   0.12   0.13   0.05
Gene5   0.44   0.53   0.46   0.03   0.47
Gene6   NA     0.34   NA     0.8    NA
Gene7   0.49   0.55   0.67   0.49   0.89
Gene8   0.25   NA     0.49   NA     NA
Gene9   0.1    0.1    0.05   NA     0.09
```

So the resulting file should be as follows:

```
        C1     C2     C3     C4     C5
Gene1   0.07   NA     0.05   0.07   0.07
Gene2   0.2    0.18   0.16   0.15   0.15
Gene4   0.32   0.05   0.12   0.13   0.05
Gene5   0.44   0.53   0.46   0.03   0.47
Gene7   0.49   0.55   0.67   0.49   0.89
Gene9   0.1    0.1    0.05   NA     0.09
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you deciding which `NA` values to remove?

Comment: Hi Tim, It does not depend which NAs. It is only if there are more than 30% NAs for a particular row, then to remove the row completely.

Comment: What have you attempted? Show some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subset based on the row sums of NA values:

```
test[!rowSums(is.na(test)) > ncol(test)*.3,]

        C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
Gene1 0.07   NA 0.05 0.07 0.07
Gene2 0.20 0.18 0.16 0.15 0.15
Gene4 0.32 0.05 0.12 0.13 0.05
Gene5 0.44 0.53 0.46 0.03 0.47
Gene7 0.49 0.55 0.67 0.49 0.89
Gene9 0.10 0.10 0.05   NA 0.09
```

Comment: I would go for `dat[rowMeans(is.na(dat)) <= .3,]`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another version with `Reduce`

```
df1[!Reduce(`+`, lapply(df1, is.na)) > ncol(df1)*0.3,]
#       C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
#Gene1 0.07   NA 0.05 0.07 0.07
#Gene2 0.20 0.18 0.16 0.15 0.15
#Gene4 0.32 0.05 0.12 0.13 0.05
#Gene5 0.44 0.53 0.46 0.03 0.47
#Gene7 0.49 0.55 0.67 0.49 0.89
#Gene9 0.10 0.10 0.05   NA 0.09
```

Comment: dat[Reduce(`+`, lapply(dat, is.na)) < ncol(dat)*0.3,] gives same result.

Answer (score 4):

And here another option using apply

```
dat[apply(dat,1,function(x){sum(is.na(x))/dim(dat)[2]})<0.3,]

#C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
#Gene1 0.07   NA 0.05 0.07 0.07 
#Gene2 0.20 0.18 0.16 0.15 0.15
#Gene4 0.32 0.05 0.12 0.13 0.05
#Gene5 0.44 0.53 0.46 0.03 0.47
#Gene7 0.49 0.55 0.67 0.49 0.89
#Gene9 0.10 0.10 0.05   NA 0.09
```